# Create Table from Query IN PLSQL

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

Since complex query takes long time to execute so I want to create a table to keep for future use, I don't want to execute it again. so my idea is that I want to create a table by insert query result into it.
The below is my sample code. It is not working it is just my idea. Thanks

```
DECLARE
   with tab_emp as (    
    select * from employees
    ),
    tab_dept as 
    (select * from departments)
   
    procedure create_tab_from_query IS 
    begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('create table mytest as  select * from '|| tab_emp || ' where 1=0');
    end create_tab_from_query;
BEGIN
    create_tab_from_query;
    dbms_output.put_line(abc);
END;
/
```

Comment: Put the entire query inside execute immediate (as a string) ...

Comment: tab_emp is a cursor. You cannot simply use that in a string concatenation. You could put the whole cursor SQL in the string, though, and then it could work, provided you got all the rights and access. Whether you should is a different story. A table like this can be useful for temporary use, but if you want to keep it, maybe you're actually looking for a view?

Comment: Lot's of discussion here about the technical solution, but I can't help but wonder if this is not just another 'x-y problem'.  From your description, it sounds to me like all you need is a materialized view, instead of jumping through hoops to 'create a table in pl/sql'.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
SQL> with t2 as (select * from t) select * from t2;

L     A
--------- ------------------------------------------------------
RUS       Русский
```

But you cannot use WITH in a CREATE TABLE statement as you would like to use.
This cannot work:

```
SQL> with t2 as (select * from t) create table t3 as select * from t2;
with t2 as (select * from t) create table t3 as select * from t2
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

You should try something simpler without `WITH` clause:

```
SQL> create table t3 as select * from t;

Table created.
```

In your case your PL/SQL code could be simplified this way:

```
SQL> --
SQL> BEGIN
  2     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
  3      create table mytest as select * from employees where 1=0');
  4      dbms_output.put_line('abc');
  5  END;
  6  /
abc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: are you sure, that you are unswerving OP's question ? OP is asking about 'creating table IN PLSQL'....

Comment: You are right but there is no point in trying to create a table in PL/SQL if the SQL statement used to create the table is an invalid SQL statement. First get the SQL statement right and then you can build it dynamically if needed in PL/SQL.

Comment: As long as your're aware :) May be you could mention that at the beginning of your answer..to make thing clearer.

Comment: OK I have added a solution in PL/SQL.